# Lambda - C# - Dynamic expressions, using string.IsNullOrEmpty

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, expression

I have the following code block I am using to perform some dynamic filtering on a generic IQueryable list

```
    private static MethodInfo miTL = typeof(String).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);

    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string member, object value)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        if (member == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("member");
        }
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }

        if (value is string && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            //If the type is string, force lowercase equals comparison for both sides.
            value = value.ToString().ToLower();

            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
            var parameterProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, member);

            //ToLower dynamic expression
            var dynamicExpression = Expression.Call(parameterProperty, miTL);

            var constantValue = Expression.Constant(value);
            var equalsExpression = Expression.Equal(dynamicExpression, constantValue);

            var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalsExpression, parameter);

            return source.Where(lambdaExpression);
        }
        else
        {
            var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
            var prop = Expression.Property(item, member);
            var soap = Expression.Constant(value);
            var equal = Expression.Equal(prop, soap);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equal, item);
            return source.Where(lambda);
        }
    }
```

This all works fine - apart from the possibility of my source containing null values, which then returns a null reference exception.

It directly translates to (when the field is "Counterparty" :- {item => (item.Counterparty.ToLower() == "name of counterparty")}

What I actually need in Lambda expression form is :-

{item => !string.IsNullEmptyOrWhitespace(item.Counterparty) && (item.Counterparty.ToLower() == "name of counterparty")}

Any ideas how to achieve this dynamically?

--REVIEWED--

Here is the whole replacement code, using a much nicer string.Equals check

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string member, object value)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        if (member == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("member");
        }
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }

        if (value is string && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
            var parameterProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, member);

            var body =
                Expression.AndAlso(
                    Expression.Not(
                        Expression.Call(typeof(string), "IsNullOrEmpty", null, parameterProperty)
                    ),
                    Expression.Call(typeof(string), "Equals", null,
                        parameterProperty, Expression.Constant(value),
                        Expression.Constant(System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                );

            var body2 = Expression.Call(typeof(string), "Equals", null,
                parameterProperty, Expression.Constant(value),
                Expression.Constant(System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

            return source.Where(lambdaExpression);
        }
        else
        {
            var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
            var prop = Expression.Property(item, member);
            var soap = Expression.Constant(value);
            var equal = Expression.Equal(prop, soap);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equal, item);
            return source.Where(lambda);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A literal translation would be something like:

```
var body =
    Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.Not(
            Expression.Call(typeof(string), "IsNullOrWhiteSpace", null,
                                                       parameterProperty)
        ),
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Call(parameterProperty, "ToLower", null),
            Expression.Constant("name of counterparty")
        )
    );
```

However, you would do well to look at the various `string.Equals` overloads. For example:

```
var body = Expression.Call(typeof(string), "Equals", null,
    parameterProperty, Expression.Constant("name of counterparty"),
    Expression.Constant(System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Hi Marc, I would have preferred to use something more like !string.IsNullEmptyOrWhitespace(item.Value) && item.Value.Equals(otherLiteral, CurrentCulture.IgnoreCase) - but I couldn't figure out a way of doing this either?