# How to build Expression tree in C# to check if string property is just null (no empty checking)

Tags: c#, string, lambda, expression

I found how to check if a property IsNullOrEmpty using:

```
var methodCall = Expression.Call(typeof(string), "IsNullOrEmpty", null, property);
```

But I need to check only if the property is null. Not check empty condition.

Can someone please advise me?
Thank you.

StackOverflows I passed through, but they are not my case and not helped:

- [Lambda - C# - Dynamic expressions, using string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828501/lambda-c-sharp-dynamic-expressions-using-string-isnullorempty)
- [Null check for lambda expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948920/null-check-for-lambda-expression-tree)

The result should be an equiqalent to:

```
class A
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
}

A a = new A();

// this I need to construct with Expressions:  
bool isNull = a.Text == null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Expression.Equal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.equal?view=net-7.0):

```
var exp = Expression.Equal(theInstance, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string)));
```

Next create an `VariableExpression` and assign the previous value to it:

```
exp = Expression.Assign(
    Expression.Variable(typeof(bool), "isNull"),
    exp);
```